# Could not load file or assembly 'Intelligencia.UrlRewriter' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, gac

i am installing URL rewriting DLL (from http://urlrewriter.net/) to GAC. (if i keep dll in BIN folder it works perfectly)

but keeps throwing error.

Could not load file or assembly 'Intelligencia.UrlRewriter' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (E:\Test\web.config line 28)

wondering is it because dll is http module.. and installed in GAC creating problem ? (because rest all dlls work perfectly fine in GAC)

i looked in to all internet resource for this error. but didn't find proper solution.

attached test project with dll added into bin folder.

http://rapidshare.com/files/449306116/Test.rar

please advise.

Comment: Didn't get any answers from community. at last i used microsoft support. and they suggested that. While adding reference to the URLRewriter in the Web.Config  please include Version, PublicKeyToken and Culture of the assembly, and it this worked. syntax for adding module in web.config would be. <add name="UrlRewriter"  type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule,Intelligencia.UrlRewriter, Version=?, PublicKeyToken=???, Culture=neutral " /> hope this saves someone's time( i wasted many hours on this issue)