# URL rewriting with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I want to implement URL rewriting in my code.
I get an error :

> Could not load file or assembly 'Intelligencia.UrlRewriter' or one of
>   its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

when i try to add below section in my web.config file.

```
 <httpModules>
      <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/> 
    </httpModules>
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Refer - [Could not load file or assembly 'Intelligencia.UrlRewriter' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081677/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-intelligencia-urlrewriter-or-one-of-its-depend)

In the comments section, OP says...

> Didn't get any answers from community. at last i used microsoft support. and they suggested that. While adding reference to the URLRewriter in the Web.Config please include Version, PublicKeyToken and Culture of the assembly, and it this worked. syntax for adding module in web.config would be. `<add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule,Intelligencia.UrlRewriter, Version=?, PublicKeyToken=???, Culture=neutral " />` hope this saves someone's time( i wasted many hours on this issue)

Comment: I had referred this solution.But even this is giving me error as:The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)

Comment: What is the `Version` and `PublicKeyToken`, which you have tried?